# select significant values having mean and standard deviation

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `Data (n x m)` containing my data (averages between groups).
n is the number of "parameter of interest" (for example, height, weight etc.)
m is group of people (group 1 ,group 2 etc.)
`Error` is a matrix (n x m) containing the standard deviations of Data.

Now I would like to select only the significant data...
For example if Data and Error are (2 x 3) (n = weight, high; m = group1 group2 group3)

```
Data = [4.12502560163850,4.51407107506505, 0.592984328663462;
5.29560931899642,5.26306387164821,0.525691390848871];
Error = [12.0003478648892, 12.4431683689277, 1.77834685956325;
10.3910686148834,17.1175178471769,1.33979258445445]
```

I would like to select only the values of Data that are significant. i.e 
(height of group 1 - standard deviation of height group 1 should be > height of group 2 + standard deviation of height group 2)
or
(height of group 1 - standard deviation of height group 1 should be > height of group 3 + standard deviation of height group 3).

In this particular case I could do

```
k = 1; 

for i = 1: size(Data,1)

  if ((Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,2)+Error(i,2)) || (Data(i,1)-Error(i,1)) > (Data(i,3)+Error(i,3)))

   selectedpar(k) = i;

   k = k+1;

end
```

My trouble is that I don't know in advance the dimensions of Data and I would make the if condition dynamic...

Thanks

Comment: use `size( Data )` to get the `n` and `m`.

Comment: yes I know the size command :).
Maybe I was not clear...the problem is that with the increase of groups I've to compare a value with other n values...
if a > b || a > c || a > d ....

Comment: use `bsxfun` and vectorrize.

Comment: I edited the question...I hope now it is more clear..

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, still need improve to be without for-loop but I don't have time for it.

```
myDataLen = 1:size(Data,2);
selectedpar = [];
for i = 1:size(Data,2)    
    otherIndice = find(myDataLen ~= i);
    for j = 1:size(otherIndice,2)
        idx = find( Data(:,i)-Error(:,i) > Data(:,otherIndice(j))+Error(:,otherIndice(j)))
        if(size(idx,1) > 0)
            selectedpar(end+1) = i;
        end         
    end    
end
```